# Configure error while Installing openmpi-3.1.6 in Windows using Cygwin64

Tags: windows, cygwin, openmpi

I downloaded openmpi-3.1.6.tar and using the cygwin terminal, I unzipped it. Afterwards, I ran the ./configure command from within the unzipped folder (/openmpi-3.1.6) and I am getting the following error-

```
checking for perl... no
configure: error: "Open MPI requires perl. Aborting"
```

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: perl is installed by default on Cygwin, so do you have it or not ? Look on the config.log for hint on the problem

Comment: It wasn't there initially. After I installed it, it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Openmpi 3.1.6 is already available as package in Cygwin

https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2020-May/009518.html

so install it from Setup